# Detecting Google Chrome Browser Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was looking for a way to detect the browser extension I am building from my website and I need to alert my users in-case they are viewing my site without it. I have been able to do this in firefox, but I want to know is there a way I can do this in Google Chrome? Even if there is a hack to get this going I am fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Create a content script specific to you site in the extension, and make it add an invisible marker in the DOM, eg:

```
$('body').append('<div style="display: none;" class="extension_enabled" />');
```

In the page, set a short timeout to check for this after the document is fully loaded, eg:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($('.extension_enabled').length > 0) {
      alert('Installed!');
    } else {
      alert('Not installed.');
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

NOTE: Code in jQuery format for simplicity. You can do it with raw javascript, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The official Google Chrome Extensions Developers' Guide has an [item](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) covering exactly this.

Comment: Unfortunately that link no longer works.  This answer works as of 2/27/2014:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13734347/2266428  with Version 32.0.1700.107 m of Chrome.