# How to check Whether an extension is installed in google chrome web browser?

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an **extension** for **Google Chrome**. I need to check every time(at the time of installation) **whether this extension is already installed ?**. I am looking for a help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check whether user has my chrome extension installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-my-chrome-extension-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection methods found [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#global-events):

Untested method

```
var myPort=chrome.extension.connect('yourextensionid_qwerqweroijwefoijwef', some_object_to_send_on_connect);
```

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-my-chrome-extension-installed)