# Checking if Chrome Extension is installed or not

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check whether user has my chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-my-chrome-extension-installed)

is there any easy way to display a div for users that have an chrome extension installed and different div for users that dont have, something like this:

```
<div>X Chrome Extension is installed</div>

<div>X Chrome Extension is not isntalled</div>
```

php or javascript something.

Comment: Well PHP is serverside so no. But with javascript you may check some specific thing being loaded / removed from DOM or whatever by some specific plugin if you are lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That's not possible.** You can't get a simple list via JavaScript.

You could only check for things which specific extensions introduce (e.g. new DOM elements, etc.).

You cannot accomplish any client-side checks with PHP because it is interpreted and run on the server side.