# How do you check if a Chrome Extension is enabled?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There are lots of examples and approaches to check for installation status.

Can someone point me to some example code (fiddle?) which checks that the extension is installed **and** enabled?

Or, just the enabled bit will suffice since the check of an install is not the issue and I can combine myself.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed

Comment: @Mario Thanks. Yes, I did see the getElementById approach before and it seems straightforward. I like the direct approach better but can't grasp it. So, that one with a code example would be nice.