# Check if Chrome Extension is installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I currently have the code below. This, however, always redirects to google. I don't get why though.

**HTML**

```
<script>
function load(){
    if (typeof extension == 'undefined') {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="load()">
```

**inject.js from the extension**

```
(function () {
 var extension = 11;
}());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in a content script runs in an [isolated world](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), in which it can't directly affect javascript running in the main page. However, you can [communicate through the page's DOM, including with `window.postMessage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication). You might create a DOM node with a known value in order to signal that the extension is running.

You'll also need to set [content_scripts.run_at](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at) to either `'document_start'` or `document_end` in order to guarantee that the content script runs before the document's `onload` event where you're checking that the extension exists.