# Getting error while detect chrome extension installed or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Here is My code,

```
var myExtension = chrome.management.get( "my_extention_id" );
if (myExtension.enabled)
{
// installed
}
else { ... }
```

source : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-get
i have tried this method. But i'm getting following error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's unclear. Are you detecting from another extension, from a regular webpage? Is this an extension you control?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's undefined then you're missing the management declaration in the manifest:

```
"permissions": [
          "management"
        ],
```

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management)

Comment: Dear @Omri Aharon , chrome.management.get... , returns this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` , In calling from external page. Also as we use nativeMessaging and MessagePassing we insert in the permissions these values: `NativeMessaging`,  `tabs` and `some patern like http://*/*` and `management`.

Answer (score 6):

#### Check in another extension:

https://gist.github.com/greatghoul/321b4f32c0b7a6ad8a97

#### Check in webpage

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

In manifest file, remember to register webpage you want to check extension from.

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://developer.chrome.com/*"]
}
```

then you can use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in that page.