# Jquery auto popup with google chrome extension install check

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make an auto popup in my website with jquery working only at Google Chrome and it will be like this :

if you use Google Chrome to surf my website and you don't install my Google Chrome extension the popup will show with a button to install the extension, and if you are already install my **extension** or you don't use Google Chrome the popup will not show

Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: nothing :/ I don't have any background about this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a number of things to accomplish this, and you'll probably have to work through the code yourself, but to get you on a path:

**Check if browser is chrome**: [JavaScript: How to find out if the user browser is Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565112/javascript-how-to-find-out-if-the-user-browser-is-chrome)

**Check if your chrome extension is installed**: This is actually the trickiest part, you'll need to build a way of doing it into your chrome extension likely.  I have seen two main methods of this:

1) Putting a tag on every page you can check (or just the page you want to do it on).

2) Putting an externally pingable item to check for: [Getting error while detect chrome extension installed or not using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166278/how-to-detect-chrome-extension-installed-or-not-using-javascript)

**To install chrome inline**: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation