# Detect Google chrome extension using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am building a script, and I need a JS script to detect chrome extension and perform action when extension found using CSS & HTML, example if extension is found then the download button will vanish.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed

Comment: thanks Ankita the comment helped me a lot

Comment: Search for answer before asking question.Otherwise your question will be down voted if it is duplicate.

Comment: OK I will search before questioning