# How to prevent chrome extension to mess with my site events?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using mousewheel event in my site. I have webgl frontend, scrollbars disabled, mousewheel is used for manipulating objects. Works good, if it is not Chrome with Wheel Smooth Scroller extension. This bastard scrolls page not meant to be scrolled, and moreover - blocks my mousewheel event.

I attach event listener like this:

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseWheel);
```

What should I do? Attaching event to some div instead of window IS NOT AN OPTION

Comment: Disable the extension?

Comment: did you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed

Comment: Read. So, I should detect extension and send a message to it, that says to bypass my page? And if extension has no such message, Im stuck, OK. In that case, how to list all available messages for some certain extension?