# How can I tell if a specific internet browser app is enabled

Tags: javascript

How can I tell if a user enables an app in their browser?

i.e., A chrome user has Rikaikun installed. On my site they enable it. How can I detect if they've just enabled it?

Do I set up some sort of javascript listener? The reason I ask is that the developers console shows javascript being executed when I enable Rikaikun.

Is there a programmatic way to detect this?

edit: grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page [Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed) has instructions on detecting Chrome extensions, which Rikaikun seems to be.

They all seem fairly easy to test yourself so it shouldn't take long to work out whether that provides a solution or not.

Comment: This helps me a lot. Thank you!