# How to access firefox/chrome extension details from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

this question might have already asked by someone, but I did not find any correct reference of the question.

I am developing a webpage and I am enabling a button based on whether FireSSH extension is installed or not. Do you have any suggestions on how to write using javascript/angularjs?  I understand that due to security reasons java script code is not allowed to access extension.  I want to take expert opinion if there is any way.

Kiran

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/2EaKD/422/

Comment: i think plugin and extensions are different. I have FireSSH extension and the javascript is not returning that.  This jsfiddle is not returning anything if i run on Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed)

Comment: In Firefox there is no way you can check for addons. They are completely separate and kept away. Only way you can check, is if the addon exposes something to webpages for the check. So if it's your own addon you can easily hook something up.