# Detect Chrome extension by ID

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to detect if a user has a Chrome extension, and if so, log something to the console (I will change what it does later on, but keeping it simple for now)

I only have the extension ID< I cannot modify the manifest or anything related to the extension.

I have tried many things, such as the `management` API, but that requires manifest permissions.

I need this to be able to run in-page, not in extension.

Things I have tried:

```
chrome.extension.connect(theidhere, andafunctionhere)
chrome.management.get(theidhere, andafunctionhere
And a function I found here on SO that was too big to paste.
```

Is there anyway to log to the console if a certain extension ID is found, and for it to work in between `<script>` tags in a standard `.html` document?

EDIT: Before someone possibly marks this as a duplicate, I am aware of [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbqoWora7QAhVCPrwKHWc8BBoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8946325%2Fchrome-extension-id-how-to-find-it&usg=AFQjCNFgKPjcfr_Pim51iX6X62RyxTKKJg&bvm=bv.139138859,d.dGc) question, and [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbqoWora7QAhVCPrwKHWc8BBoQFggrMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27930016%2Fdetect-if-a-chrome-extension-is-installed&usg=AFQjCNHlL1Rw1_3b8w0RiSAOFMT5VTEQcA&bvm=bv.139138859,d.dGc) question.

Comment: No, that would be a violation of user privacy.

Comment: Potentially a better duplicate: [How to detect extension on a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356596/how-to-detect-extension-on-a-browser).  Related: [Can websites tell what addons are installed in a Firefox web browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319204/can-websites-tell-what-addons-are-installed-in-a-firefox-web-browser)

Comment: Similar question asked 11 days ago: [Detect if specific Browser Extension is installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437609/detect-if-specific-browser-extension-is-installed) and 15 days ago: [How to detect extension on a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356596/how-to-detect-extension-on-a-browser)