# How to detect specific extension installed in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can a detect a specific extension(like extension X) installed in google chrome. I search for it but most of the answer is detecting self extensions. That is first create an extension and then detect this extension by it's any element. But I need to detect an extension which is not created by me and installed from chrome web store.

Comment: Do you want to detect it inside your own extension? If so, see chrome.management API. Otherwise, there's no universal method, you'll have to see what that other extension does in page DOM/events.

Comment: Duplicates/related: [Check if user has a third party Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39897925), [How to detect extension on a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40356596), and for Firefox: [Can websites tell what addons are installed in a Firefox web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39319204)

Answer (score -1):

Visit this link and you can use most the the connection methods here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#global-events

The chrome.extension API has utilities that can be used by any extension page. It includes support for exchanging messages between an extension and its content scripts or between extensions, as described in detail in Message Passing.