# How to retrieve list of chrome extension, bookmarks using google admin sdk

Tags: google-chrome, google-admin-sdk

I am searching different ways to retrieve list of extensions installed by users using their organization email id into chrome. We can find it by writing extension that uses Chrome Management API. Is there any way we can retrieve list using Admin SDK (Directory API or Reports API), since google is linking user accounts to browser upon chrome login and associates bookmarks, extensions to it using email id. I checked google documentation and also admin.google.com, but cannot find any details.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that Directory or Reports API don't support retrieving list of extensions installed by users. I can only see the `chrome.management` API which provides ways to manage the list of extensions/apps that are installed and running. The [`chrome.management.getAll`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-getAll) method returns a list of information about installed extensions and apps. Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will checkout this option