# Detect if a Chrome extension is installed by users

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried all solutions in this question

[Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed)

what I  did:

1-  I added background js file and in manifest  I added the following

```
 "background": {
       "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
       "persistent": true
   },

   "permissions": [ "https://*.mydomain.com/*" ],
```

in background.js I added

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if ((msg.action == "id") && (msg.value == id))
    {
        sendResponse({id : id});
    }
});
```

and in my website I added this code

```
<script>
    var id = "madbfblbpcoiddlankhkdbagjeemnlof";
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(id, {action: "id", value : id}, function(response) {
        if(response && (response.id == id)) //extension installed
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
        else //extension not installed
        {
            console.log("Please consider installig extension");
        }

    });
</script>
```

and I always get Please consider installig extension

How can I fix this issue ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your `id` at the start of your `background.js` like so: `var id = chrome.runtime.id;`.

Also you need to add your site to the `externally_connectable` instead of the `permissions` in the `manifest.json` as:

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["https://*.mydomain.com/*"]
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm  I didn't know about externally_connectable . thank you for your help  you saved me