# Listen to chrome extension installation in app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-redux

How can I listen/track when chrome extension is installed from the web store?
I previously had an inline installation of the extension but by inline installations coming to an end soon, I want the user action to open the web store to install the extension and listen for when they add the extension for UI changes and act based on that.

I tried the messaging approach found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043701/4099436) but it seems not working.

*manifest.json* looks like:

```
   "background": {
     "scripts":["index.js"],
     "persistent": false
   },
   "permissions": ["desktopCapture"],
   "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
            "*://localhost:*/*",
         "https://*.stageten.tv/*"
        ]
    }
```

and *index.js* :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request === screenShareExtensionId) {
          if (request.message) {
              if (request.message == "version") {
                  sendResponse({version: 1.0})
                  alert('Hiiii')
              }
          }
      }
      return true;
  })
```

and inside my app:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(screenShareExtensionId, { message: "version" },
    function (reply) {
        if (reply) {
            if (reply.version) {
              return true;
            }
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
    })
```

and based on the value in my redux logic, the UI either changes or not/waits for the extension to get installed.

Comment: Simply send an http request to your server via XMLHttpRequest in your extension? Or enumerate the open tabs, find the one with your site and run a content script there that posts a message to your site via DOM CustomEvent or window.postMessage?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it at the start of your [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

You need to save a flag (for example, it can be a version of the extension) to the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

After that, on each start of the background page, you need to check if this flag is in your storage. If there is no flag - then you need to track install, otherwise, it's just usual reload of the background page.

The same way can be used to track updates of the extension from the store, just need to compare versions.

Comment: So, the background page does not run until the extension is installed and it seems that it is not running in my app at all, cause I am not seeing an alert or receiving any changes in the script file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this this in [this self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353104/1814486), which I can't mark as a duplicate of this because of no accepted/up votes.

---

Here's how I solved it from the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (w/o using a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)):

### `background.js`

- Listen for `onInstalled` event.
- Query all opened tabs that match the URL's you want to notify.
- Execute a small script in each tab that will [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) notifying
  that installation was succesful.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function listener(details) {
  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
      url: [
        'https://localhost:3000/*',
        'https://staging.foo.com/*',
        'https://production.foo.com/*'
      ]
    }, tabs => {
      Array.from(tabs).forEach(tab => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
          code: `window.postMessage('screenshare-ext-installed', window.origin);`
        });
      });
    });

    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.removeListener(listener);
  }
});
```

### `manifest.json`

Just make sure both `externally_connectable` and `permissions` declare
the URL patterns of the sites you want to notify.

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
    "https://localhost:3000/*",
    "https://staging.foo.com/*",
    "https://production.foo.com/*"
  ]
},
"permissions": [
  "desktopCapture",
  "https://localhost:3000/*",
  "https://staging.foo.com/*",
  "https://production.foo.com/*"
],
```

### Web page

Just listen somewhere for the `postMessage` message fired by
the extension on succesful installation.

```
window.onmessage = e => {
  if (e.data === 'screenshare-ext-installed') {
    // extension successfully installed
    startScreenShare()
  }
}
```

### Credits

- [@wOxxOm's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347230/detect-when-chrome-extension-was-installed-without-inline-installation#comment91640198_52347230)