# Detect when Chrome extension was installed, without inline installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

How can an open tab get notified that a Chrome extension has just been installed, when the installation was done through the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) instead of inline-installation?

### Context

Since June 2018 and onwards [Chrome has deprecated inline installation](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/06/improving-extension-transparency-for.html) hence the following mechanism to get notified if extension was installed *won't work* from now on:

```
chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)
```

From now on extensions *must* be installed only via the Web Store.

We've built a screen share extension that allows prompting the user to share his screen.

When our users hit "Share Screen", we intend to redirect them to the Chrome extension within the Web Store and as soon as they install the extension to re-trigger the Share Screen functionality.

Comment: Your extension can send a https/https request in its chrome.runtime.onInstalled listener when the parameter indicates a new install.

Comment: @wOxxOm That seems rather complicated. Send an https:// request to whom? Our web server, so it can notify the UI? Isn't there a way we can just send a message to the webpage from the extension?

Comment: Of course: run your extension's content script in that tab using chrome.tabs.query and chrome.tabs.executeScript, then the content script can send a custom DOM event via document.dispatchEvent.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's what I've done and it works fine. Care to write up a tad more detailed answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it from the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (w/o using a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)):

### `background.js`

- Listen for `onInstalled` event.
- Query all opened tabs that match the URL's you want to notify.
- Execute a small script in each tab that will [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) notifying
  that installation was succesful.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function listener(details) {
  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
      url: [
        'https://localhost:3000/*',
        'https://staging.foo.com/*',
        'https://production.foo.com/*'
      ]
    }, tabs => {
      Array.from(tabs).forEach(tab => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
          code: `window.postMessage('screenshare-ext-installed', window.origin);`
        });
      });
    });

    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.removeListener(listener);
  }
});
```

### `manifest.json`

Just make sure both `externally_connectable` and `permissions` declare
the URL patterns of the sites you want to notify.

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
    "https://localhost:3000/*",
    "https://staging.foo.com/*",
    "https://production.foo.com/*"
  ]
},
"permissions": [
  "desktopCapture",
  "https://localhost:3000/*",
  "https://staging.foo.com/*",
  "https://production.foo.com/*"
],
```

### Web page

Just listen somewhere for the `postMessage` message fired by
the extension on succesful installation.

```
window.onmessage = e => {
  if (e.data === 'screenshare-ext-installed') {
    // extension successfully installed
    startScreenShare()
  }
}
```

### Credits

- [@wOxxOm's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347230/detect-when-chrome-extension-was-installed-without-inline-installation#comment91640198_52347230)