# Check chrome extension installed or not when extension is disabled.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How can is check chrome extension is installed or not , when extension is disabled ?

I found that when extension is disabled we can not access the background.js and also its icon.png or manifest.json.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed

Comment: I want to check extension is disable or not and at the time of extension disable background.js not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

While the extension is disabled, both the background script and the content script are alive, but the communication medium is disabled. So you can't send messages between them.

Can be captured using

```
chrome.runtime.connect().onDisconnect.addListener(function(e) {});
```

In the worst case, you can do a `POST` message.

Answer (score 0):

If a extension is disabled, any code in it would not work, so it is not possible to get the installation status from a disabled extension

Answer (score 0):

You can capture using

```
chrome.runtime.connect().onDisconnect.addListener(function(e) {

    ...

});
```

Comment: Consider adding a code example to your answer.