# Show alert instead of downlading a file

Tags: javascript, php

My website contains this live stream:

https://content.uplynk.com/channel/3324f2467c414329b3b0cc5cd987b6be.m3u8

If there is no any [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/native-hls-playback/emnphkkblegpebimobpbekeedfgemhof) installed, when I click  the link it downloads a .m3u8 file

How can I show an alert so that my visitors know they need that extension?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can check installed extensions by chrome API. check out this answer.

[Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed)

Comment: I can't find the solution. I'd like something like: if (extension.installed == 'true') {...}
An example would be greatly appreciated.