# Detecting specific chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, api

I want to detect if user has IDM (internet download manager) extension installed in his browser...how can I do it?

I tried using navigator.plugin but it doesn't work

Comment: If you're the author of the extension, you can do one of the things suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/q/6293498/14215102 . If you're trying to detect someone else's extension from a webpage, that's intentionally not possible.