# Find if user has a Google calendar add-on installed from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

There is documentation about [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) on a Chrome extension

as well as a few Stack Overflow links on how to [check whether a user has a Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed) from a web page

But, I've been doing some research and I haven't found a definite answer on whether a Chrome extension (or even a web page) can tell if a Google add-on is installed or not. I was hoping add-ons would have the same message passing option extensions have, but it doesn't look like to be the case. If not, any potential workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

By reading your question, What I understand is, you want to know if a particular extension like  is installed or not in your browser.

If that is the question then, yes we can get that details using chrome extension,
Follow these steps,
**First**

- Add **management** permission in your manifest.json file.

**Second**

- Use chrome API of management which gives you details of all installed extensions
- I used the API on extension click.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    chrome.management.getAll((allExtension) => {
        console.log('allExtension: ', allExtension);
    });
});
```

**Reference**

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#type-ExtensionInfo

I hope, I gave you the right answer.