# How to run js script only when chrome extension is active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to run the javascript file only when someone clicks on the chrome extension. I know you can run scripts when the extension is clicked but is there a way to also stop the script from running when the extension is inactive?

Comment: It depends on what exactly the scripts do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending a request to the extension and make your logic based on the response you receive.

Check [Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Why not always inject the code like:

````
// inject.js
const runOn = ()=> { ...}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((response, sendResponse) => {
          runOn()
});

// Then at click something like this

chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,"your message"); 

```


Or maybe use 

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "/my-page.html"}).then(() => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: `console.log('location:', window.location.href);`
  });
});

```
````