# Detecting UI Elements of Browser Extension using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In the Google Chrome browser, I have installed the *'Roboform' extension*. [This extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/roboform-password-manager/pnlccmojcmeohlpggmfnbbiapkmbliob) creates some **UI elements** as shown in the below screenshot. *See the popup (Localhost) near login username input.*

[image]

**Question**: Is there a way to detect 'Roboform' created UI elements with JavaScript?

### What I have tried

- I tried to use dev tools to inspect the popup element. But I could not see/inspect.
- I also tried to detect the extension using [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed). But could not get it to work.

Comment: If it's a DOM element, it can be inspected in devtools. If you installed a separate external utility then it's outside of the browser and you can't inspect it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I installed an extension called 'Robofont' from the Chrome Web Store. I can't inspect its popup element with devtools. Therefore, it should be taken as a separate external utility (cannot use JavaScript to detect it).

Comment: What *exactly* do you hope to accomplish by detecting the presence of these UI elements?

Comment: @esqew If those UI elements are present, and that information can be sent with the sign-in form submission, then it will help to identify real users from spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps**

1. Ctrl+Shift+I Or RightClick->Inspect to open dev tools
2. Ctrl+Shift+C Or Click on the Selection Tool

[image]

3. Select the UI component you want with the selection tool.
4. You can see it is under a closed #shadow-root 'div.overlay-content-mini'

[image]

If you want to know more about Shadow DOM, read the following article.

[What the Heck is Shadow DOM?](https://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/)

**Note**: *Closed shadow roots are not very useful. Some developers will see closed mode as an artificial security feature. Read more [here](https://web.dev/shadowdom-v1/).*

[image]